# ScrollView not fitting screen and not scrolling horizontally

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I have a ContentView that has a Grid, name Grid1. Inside of that Grid, I then have an Entry in row 0 and Grid, named Grid2 in row 1.

The data inside of the Grid2 display but falls off the view of the WinUI and has no scroll options.  I then add a ScrollView over Grid2 and now Grid2 doesn't fall off the WinUI but it resizes and only takes the Entry's ColumnDefinition of 200 and still doesn't have any scrolling option.

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I am trying to get the view to scroll as inside the Grid2.  I have tried to set the width for the Grid2 so its larger than the ScrollView as recommend but the results remain the same and there are no scrolling options.

The full code is here:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="DiME.Controls.ReliabilityIncidentContentView">

<Grid x:Name="Grid1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Entry Placeholder="Search Text here" 
        TextColor="AliceBlue"
        TextChanged="Entry_TextedChanged"></Entry>
    <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Both">
         <Grid  x:Name="Grid2" Grid.Column="0" ColumnSpacing="1" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Black}"
    VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--...many defs ...-->
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!--..labels content...-->
            <CollectionView Grid.Row="1">                        
                <!--...content..-->
            </CollectionView>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

Without the ScrollView the CollectionView and Grid2 doesn't resize as such:

[image]

With the ScrollView (Scrolling doesn't move text):

[image]

Comment: "only fills with ColumnDefinition of Grid.Row 0".  I have no idea what that means.  Please try to describe the problem more clearly.  A screenshot may help.  And please be clear about which Grid (you have two) you are referring to.

Comment: @Jason thank you for the feedback and have updated.

Comment: this `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` belongs on the `ScrollView`

Comment: @Jason thanks - that fixed the first issue but I am still unable to scroll horizontally.

Comment: you can only scroll if the contents of the scrollview are larger than the scrollview itself.  There are no width settings that I see on the contents of the scrollview that would cause them to be larger than the scrollview

Comment: @Jason that helps a lot - I believe I have resolved it.

Comment: Glad you solved it. You could post an answer and accept it below, which may help others with similar questions. And here is the document you may also refer to: [ScrollView as a root layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview#scrollview-as-a-root-layout)